# Реализация записи в БД со страницы с помощью JS ( vue-js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, view, vue.js

Здравствуйте.

Как правильно и как можно реализовать запись данных со страницы в бд?

Вот на этом форуме есть у каждой темы рейтинг, который можно опускать и поднимать.

Можно ли будет реализовать такой рейтинг с помощью JS скриптов, в частности с помощью фреймворка vue-js, чтобы рейтинг сохранялся в БД, к примеру в MySQL, и при следующей загрузки страницы, выводился текущий рейтинг, а не снова сбрашивался до нулевого значения?

Интересна сама реализация, как это будет все происходит.

Заранее благодарен.)

Можно будет ли пример реализации, что да как нужно делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

имхо распространенная схема выглядит следующим образом:
1) js - на клиенте обрабатывает, например, действие пользователя по оценке (пользователь ставит тот или иной рейтинг); далее отправляет например ajax'ом на серверную сторону на какой-нибудь .php скрипт, 
2) который в свою очередь получает данные от клиента и заносит в ту же бд

Comment: Хм. Будем пытаться реализовать. 
Спасибо,@EugeneEvstafiev. )