# Js (vue-js) связать с back end и занести данные в БД

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Хочу узнать как реализовать и увидеть примеры реализации записи в Бд данных, полученных от Js.

Мне давали ответ в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/698993/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-js-vue-js) , но от части, мало что понял.

К примеру есть заготовка для вью:

```js
new Vue({
        el: '#example-1',
        data: {
            counter: 0
        },
        methods:{
            increase: function () {
                this.counter++;
            },
            zero: function () {
                this.counter=0;
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="example-1">
    <button v-on:click="increase">Добавляй</button>
    <button v-on:click="zero">Обнуляй</button>
    <p> {{ counter }} </p>
</div>
```

Контроллер для неё выглядит очень просто:

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
...

class SiteController extends Controller
{
.....
public function actionTest2()
    {
        return $this->render('test2');
    }
....
}
```

БД в проекте подключена, все работает.  Использую фреймворк Yii2.

Можно будет написать что нужно будет сделать, чтобы вносить значения в бд. Если есть какие-либо примеры, то буду очень благодарен.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: используйте Ajax и функционал yii2

Comment: @SOFQ3 можно по подробнее, пожалуйста. 
Буду очень признателен. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на js отправляете данные на php получаете, как получили добавляем в БД.

```
//Controller file code
public function actionAjax()
        {
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post('test');
            if (isset($data)) {
                $test = "Ajax Worked!";
            } else {
                $test = "Ajax failed";
            }
            return \yii\helpers\Json::encode($test);
        }




//_form.php code 
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

        function sendFirstCategory() {
            var test = "this is an ajax test";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('cases/ajax')  ; ?>",
                data: {test: test},
                success: function (test) {
                    alert(test);
                },
                error: function (exception) {
                    alert(exception);
                }
            })
            ;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: а можно вопрос, для лучшего понимания. файл _form.php будет где расположен? Извини, если трачу время, чтобы разжевать.

Comment: это view файл. но если есть подключенные js файлы то можно и туда запихать этот код

Comment: так. Разобрался куда вставлять _form.php. 
Но вопрос. Вот код, который ты предоставил для контролера, как я понял,он служит для проверки работоспособности Ajax. Но для чего нужен _form.php?

Comment: да не обязательно _form.php это просто для примера ты код вставь туда где у тебя кнопка, это просто js код который должен подгружаться вместе с твоей страницей при render в папке view которая. В твоем случаи это `return $this->render('test2');`  вот в test2 и запихай его.