# Передача данных из контроллера во вьюху с помощью vue-js

Tags: yii2, vue.js

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь разобраться подробно [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701050/js-vue-js-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-back-end-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94/701071?noredirect=1#comment1041450_701071) . Для этого решил взять полегче вариант.

Вот есть контроллер( фреймворк Yii2)

```
 <?php namespace app\controllers;
   use ...
 class SiteController extends Controller
  {
   ...
    public function actionTest()
     {
       $data = Yii::$app->request->post('test');
       $test = "Тестовое сообщение,выведи его!";
       return $this->render('test7',['test'=>$test]);
     }
  }
```

Он выводит страницу test и передает туда строку $test.

На странице есть JS код (фреймворк jue-js)

```js
 new Vue({
        el: '#example-1',
        data: {
            counter: 0,
            test: ""
        },
        mounted: function(){
              this.test = "...(Тут должно быть сообщение)..."
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="example-1">
    <p> {{test}}</p>
</div>
```

Вот как вывести текст, что передает контроллер с помощью vue?

Понимаю, что это должно передаваться в сообщение

```
    mounted: function(){
              this.test = "...(Тут должно быть сообщение)..."
        }
```

Заранее благодарен. Уже столько раз помогали разобраться. )
Спасибо.

PS: уточнение для ясности вопроса.

Немного полазил погуглил. Нужно реализоваться передачу строки с помощью ajax используя JQuery.

Comment: Боюсь, Ваш вопрос несколько неясен. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aid Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: @Aid Конечно же выслушаю то, что вам не понятно и постараюсь объяснить. Думаю, это поможет найти ответ на мой вопрос. Что нужно будет уточнить в моём вопросе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью Jquery и ajax.

Контроллер возвращает текст.

```
public function actionTest8()
{
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post('test');
    $test = "Тестовое сообщение,выведи его!";
    return $test;
}
```

Задача в том, чтобы вывести этот текст на другой странице с помощью JS (vue-js) в отдельном блоке страницы.

Для этого, лучше всего будет использовать библиотеку Jquery c ajax.

Код страницы, на которой выводим текст:

```js
new Vue({
        el: '#example-1',
        data: {
            test: ""
        },
        mounted: function(){
            vueParent = this;
                $.ajax({                                                               
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/basic3/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftest8',  
                cache: false,
                success: function(test){
                    vueParent.test = test;
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="example-1">
    <p> {{test}}</p>

</div>
```

Получается, что в vue-js мы присвоили переменной test:

```
test: ""
```

c помощью Jquery и ajax передаваемый текст из контроллера:

```
mounted: function(){
        vueParent = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8888/basic3/web/index.php?r=site%2Ftest8',
            cache: false,
            success: function(test){
                vueParent.test = test;
            }
        });
    },
```

Надеюсь, этот простой и незатейливый пример поможет кому-то в будущем. )

Comment: а не чего что вы сначала загружаете страницу и после её загрузки отправляете ещё и ajax на сервер за данными ? когда данные можно было бы сразу разместить на странице в шаблоне, вот только как их  передать во вью ? сам сейчас с этим мучаюсь

Comment: @baneling это понятно, что можно сделать правильно, как вы написали. Но тут уже тестовый вариант, доведенный до крайности, чтобы показать как и что можно сделать. Придет новичок, как я тогда, и не будет иметь представление как вообще можно сделать ajax запрос, обратиться к определенному контроллеру. Я считаю глупо снимать баллы, когда привел простой пример и не логичный код для понимая.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
 this.test = "<?php echo $test; ?>"
...
```

Comment: Хм. Да,самый простой способ. Спасибо за ответ. )
Но тут уточнил, что бы с помощью Jquery и ajax.

Comment: а если скрипты с шаблоном лежат в разных фалах ?